# socket.emit only working for one controller AngularJS

Tags: angularjs, node.js, socket.io

Hey guys I ran into a weird issue. My `socket.emit` is working for one of my controllers, but it doesn't work for another one.

> server.js (Server side)

```
io.sockets.on('connection', function(socket){
  console.log('User ' + socket.id + ' connected');
  socket.emit('test');
});
```

> QueueController.js (Client side) (working)

```
app.controller('QueueController', ['$scope', '$location', '$rootScope', 'socket',
    function($scope, $location, $rootScope, socket){

    socket.on('chat start', function(data){
        $rootScope.$apply(function(){
            $location.path('/chat');
        });
    });

    socket.on('test', function(){
        console.log('hello world'); //this displays fine in the console
    });
});
```

> ChatController (Client side) (not working)

```
app.controller('ChatController', ['$scope', '$rootScope', 'socket', 
    function($scope, $rootScope, socket){

    socket.on('test', function(){       
        console.log('hello world'); //this does not display at all  
    });
});
```

I've read that one needs to wrap the `socket.emit` inside a

`socket.on('connect', function(){ ... }`, but that didn't work.

These are my routes:

> app.js

```
var app = angular.module('ChatApp', ['ngRoute', 'ngAnimate', 'luegg.directives', 'btford.socket-io']);

app.config(function($routeProvider, $locationProvider){
    $routeProvider
    .when('/', {
        controller:'HomeController',
        templateUrl:'views/home.html'
    })
    .when('/queue', {
        controller:'QueueController',
        templateUrl:'views/queue.html'
    })
    .when('/chat', {
        controller:'ChatController',
        templateUrl:'views/chat.html'
    })
    .otherwise({
        redirectTo: '/'
    });
});
```

Any ideas what's wrong?

Comment: You are aware only one controller is active depending on your current route?

Comment: I had no idea. What must I do to switch to a new active controller? Is it possible?

Comment: When you go to http://yourapp/queue you get the template and controller you defined in your route configuration. If you go to /chat (you can type in url bar or put a link to it somewhere in the page) you get chatcontroller with it's template. If you want additional controller inside a route you need to put an element with ng-controller somewhere inside your template for that route.

Answer (score 0):

It is mostly a scope matter in your case. In your route configuration, each controller is defined to be the controller that owns the top-level scope. And when you change the pages, that top-level scope controller is switched over together.

One workaround solution is build a controller that will be used in all pages, for example MasterCtrl or RootCtrl. Then you can attach that controller to body tag or html tag. Then, no matter what page you are at, that controller will fire and you can achieve multi page socket services.

```
<html ng-app='YourApp' ng-controller="MasterCtrl">
```

or

```
<body ng-app='YourApp' ng-controller="MasterCtrl">
```

However, what eventually I recommend you to do is use component (available from Angular.js 1.5). Put your scoket service in a component. Use it whatever case you need to use socket. Since components come with isolated scopes by default, you can implement the socket service without worrying of scope conflicts.

Check out this url to know further about component.
https://toddmotto.com/exploring-the-angular-1-5-component-method/